# Screen overlay when using hotkey to switch keyboard input

Tags: keyboard, macos

I've recently upgraded iMacs the other day. Can't figure out how to toggle the following overlay to show up when switching inputs using keyboard hotkeys

[image: Screenshot]

Right now the shortcut will toggle the input switch, but doesn't display the overlay below.

**EDIT**
If it helps any I am using the first gen 27" Retina 5k iMac with Yosemite 10.10.1.

Comment: Never seen that before, sure it's not a 3rd party addition?

Comment: I've disabled every known third-party addition. Fairly sure it is a system setting. I am thinking this is an Accessibility setting.

Comment: I found a guide that illustrates the overlay http://www.macosxtips.co.uk/index_files/the-input-menu-and-character-viewer.php It is activated by having the modifier key held down when initiating the input source switch. For some reason is isn't working for me on my iMac + Yosemite, but works with my 13" MBPr + Yosemite.

Comment: What shortcuts are you talking about?

Comment: The shortcut mentioned in the guide I linked, CMD+Space. I've changed the hotkey to ALT+SPACE to avoid conflicts with Spotlight. So the modifier key in this case is either CMD or ALT.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the Keyboard system preferences panel, select the Shortcuts tab then the Input Sources entry on the left.  Enable the "Select the previous input source" checkbox and assign it to the keyboard shortcut you wish.

The input source switcher window ONLY works with this shortcut.  It will not show if you use the "Select next source in Input menu" shortcut.

I'm guessing that the 2nd shortcut was added later by another developer.  Besides the lack of this secret switcher feature, notice the wording of the shortcut description.  If the same person did both, they probably would have called it "Select the next input source".

Comment: THANK YOU. This is the solution. Odd oversight by Apple on this one.

Comment: Happy to help.  Could you do me a favor and post a link to download that awesome desktop background picture?

Comment: Here you go! http://i.imgur.com/DTbfnfq.jpg

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what your set shortcut is, let's say it's `control + space`.
Simply hold down `control`, press `space` but don't release `control`. The overlay will be shown.

Also, there's no need for three input sources. I have two input sources and it works.

Comment: Yeah... Holding the modifier key isn't displaying the overlay. This is with a clean Yosemite install. I've also disabled all third-party apps to ensure there isn't any conflict.

Comment: @Viet, you do press and hold both keys for at least a second or two right? This overlay will only show up if you press and hold them for a moment.

Comment: @iksra Yes, I did hold these the keys down. I am able to display the overlay on the other Mac products I have access to: MBPr (the screenshot from the OP is from my MPBr) and five older iMacs. I'm incline to believe this is a setting issue or a specific issue with the iMac 5k Retina. I've tried reformatting the Retina 5k iMac, which hasn't yield any results.

Comment: Then I suggest you file a bug report here https://bugreport.apple.com/